# When is the infimum of the sum of two sets equal to the sum of their infima?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

When is the following true? $A$ and $B$ are subsets of real numbers. I don't say that $A$ and/or $B$
are closed:
$$\inf (A + B) = \inf (A) + \inf(B)$$

When is there a strict inequality in between? Could you give an example?
When is the equality for what sufficient condition? Could you give an example?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it is obvious that inf (A) + inf(B) <= a + b so this inequality is clear. But i am curious about equality and examples? Thank you.

Comment: How do you define $A + B$?

Comment: A+B ={a +b : a in A, b in B}

Comment: @Tunococ: I'm pretty sure $A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A\land b\in B\}$.

Comment: use the fact that $inf(A)=-sup(A)$. You can use also the factthat $sup(A+B)=sup(A)+sup(B)$=$-sup(A+B)=-sup(A)-sup(B)$=$inf(A+B)=inf(A)+inf(B)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let $a=\inf A$, $b=\inf B$. Pick $x+y\in A+B$. Then $$a\leq x,b\leq y\implies a+b\leq x+y$$

Second, let $\epsilon >0$ be given. By definition of the infimum, there exists $x$ in $A$ and $y$ in $B$ such that $$x<\inf A+\frac \epsilon 2$$ $$y<\inf B+\frac \epsilon 2$$

By summing $$x+y<\inf A+\inf B+\epsilon$$

The first step shows $$\forall z\in A+B\text{ we have }\inf A+\inf B\leq z$$

The second step shows $$\forall \epsilon >0\;\exists z\in A+B \text{ such that }z<\inf A+\inf B+\epsilon$$

This is precisely the (equivalent) definition of $\inf(A+B)$.

Comment: This does not work if any of $\inf A$ or $\inf B$ is either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

First notice that the infimum of a set $X$ exists and it's finite if and only if $X$ is non empty set bounded below so let's assume that $A$ and $B$ have these conditions.

As you said the inequality $$\inf(A)+\inf(B)\leq \inf(A+B)$$
is pretty clear so let's prove the other inequality:

We have $$\inf(A+B)-b\leq a,\, \forall a\in A, b\in B$$
so 
$$\inf(A+B)-b\leq \inf(A),\, \forall  b\in B\iff \inf(A+B)-\inf(A)\leq b,\, \forall  b\in B$$
and then
$$\inf(A+B)-\inf(A)\leq \inf(B)\iff \inf(A+B)\leq\inf(A)+ \inf(B)$$